# C# - Asynchronous call delay (HARD)

Tags: c#, .net-core

We have a financial application and each written function was designed for performance. We receive information from several exchanges via WebSocket at the same time.

We run the application in an instance of 16 cores, we receive information all the time from the 16 connected WebSockets.

Each piece of information takes an average processing time of 0.000110ms, but the problem starts with the large amount of packets received. We received an average of approximately 20,000 packets per second, which would give a processing time of 137.5ms or 13% CPU usage.

Each WebSocket receives and processes information asynchronously, but at some peak times, a single WebSocket receives many packets at the same time and processing one at a time generates a large delay of 10, 20, 30 up to 40ms at times.

So the idea would be to use a Thread Pool to solve the problem, as we would have other threads available and would balance the load of that WebSocket.

I did several tests and found that the best method would be to use the QueueUserWorkItem, but it would double the processing time of all executions.

Group 1 is called direct, representing how it is today.

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new(6, 6);

public AsyncTest()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new();
        s.Start();

        OnMessage(1, s);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new();
        s.Start();

        Task.Run(() => OnMessage(2, s));
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new();
        s.Start();

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(t => OnMessage(3, s));
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new();
        s.Start();

        ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(t => OnMessage(4, s), null);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new();
        s.Start();

        _ = Semaphore.WaitAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            OnMessage(5, s);
            Semaphore.Release();
        });
    }
}

public void OnMessage(int groupId, Stopwatch sw)
{
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(groupId + " - " + sw.Elapsed);
}
```

[image]

**Does anyone please have any idea how to process asynchronously with the least possible delay in the call?**

Comment: Dispatching work to the threadpool is unlikely to benefit you unless you have CPU intensive work.  What kind of processing do you do with these requests? Letting Windows and .NET use the natural asynchronicity of I/O processing to set up your async-ness is probably a better idea.  If you are not careful, you will also likely be throwing off a lot of garbage in your processing (though likely all Gen0 garbage). You might consider creating a buffer pool (at the very least some buffer management).  You also need to consider garbage collection costs.  Does your app ever get a chance to breathe?

Comment: You will also want to read up on `async` and `await`.  There's a much easier way to write code like: `Semaphore.WaitAsync().ContinueWith`

Comment: "at some peak times, a single WebSocket receives many packets at the same time and processing one at a time generates a large delay of 10, 20, 30 up to 40ms at times."  Why?  Perhaps Garbage Collection?  .NET Framework or .NET Core?  What GC style? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc

Comment: Don't use `Stopwatch` for timing this type of code. Instead, use the same tool the .NET Runtime team relies on. https://benchmarkdotnet.org/

Comment: What's happening in your `OnMessage` handler? David might be right that GC has a significant impact on throughput. Are you doing what you can for allocation-free coding? https://chuckconway.com/notes-writing-allocation-free-code-in-c-by-matt-ellis/

Comment: "receives and processes information asynchronously" clearly it doesn't really. If it was truly asynchronous, it would be using the ThreadPool anyway. Please show the relevant Socket code, probably you can convert this to `async` `await`

Comment: @Flydog57: I think the opposite is true. It seems there's a direct mapping of one socket to one CPU core. If the work is CPU-intensive, the best performance avoids any context switching. If `OnMessage()` has IO wait time, performing the CPU work for another message while awaiting completion of IO could lead to improved throughput.

Comment: @EricJ. There is always going to be context switching, due to Overlapped IO. Even if you block you get a context switch. The socket processing needs to be rebuilt to use asynchronous reads, then any thread that is not busy can pick up the read callback/`await` and run with it.

Comment: @Flydog57 Deserialization, calculations and sending of results. Task execution is faster than the asynchronous call. In this test benchmark I don't see how GC can influence.

Comment: @EricJ. I understand that there may be another better method, but the accuracy there is excellent to see the bottleneck.

Comment: @Charlieface The socket is TCP and the reading from the WebSocket is asynchronous from the stream. However, when I receive a packet I process with the same thread so as not to waste time, if I put this task to another thread to execute it will cost me more time than processing the task. But at peaks when we receive many packets at the same time it becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: If you are processing 20k packets/sec and you aren't thinking about GC issues, you're very likely to find that the GC is sucking up a lot of your processing power